# How to assert Listing data which is having lazy loading in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

After using this it will load more 20 records till list is not getting ended so how I can get the hall list size and how I can print the hall list data

Answer (score 0):

You can use like:

**First Approach** By pressing ctrl+end

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END);
```

**Second Approach** : By using Java Robot class

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_END);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_END);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

**OR you can use the below by extending your code**

```
 try {
        Object lastHeight = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");

        while (true) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            Object newHeight = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
            if (newHeight.equals(lastHeight)) {
                break;
            }
            lastHeight = newHeight;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```